# How to draw an image and write on it, in a logo

Tags: gimp, logo

My designer is out of reach, he has designed a logo but now there is a need to write PRO on the lower right corner of it(as written in various other logos), I am an amateur in designing, can anybody tell me how to do that in Gimp.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hello, and welcome to GD.SE! This question isn't really the best fit for our site; it's more of a "Google it!" question as this is a very basic thing to do. I'd recommend you start with the GIMP [documentation page](http://www.gimp.org/docs/)

Comment: Yeah the documentation helped a lot, Now i have started designing myself

Answer (score 2):

Open the file... use the text tool typically denoted by an icon similar to [ T ]